# Selenium webdriver throws exception when trying to run via ANT

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, selenium-webdriver

I am running my UI automation test cases using selenium via Eclipse, it goes through fine with no problem. Browsers are launched, test cases are executed, results are updated when I do it in Eclipse. Whereas, when I tried to run it via ANT, it started giving me exception,

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;`

See the attached structure of my project,
[image: Project Structure]

My ANT file(build.xml) for reference,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project name="uiAutomation" default="all" basedir=".">

<property name="example.dir" value="."/>
<property name="test.output" value="${example.dir}/build/test-output"/>
<property name="test.report" value="${example.dir}/build/test-report"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="${example.dir}/lib/dependentJars/"/>

<target name="all" depends="prepare,compile,run" />

<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- Compile Test Code                                                    -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<path id="compile.cp">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${example.dir}/src/" includes="log4j.properties"/>
</path>

<target name="prepare">
    <mkdir dir="${example.dir}/build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.output}" />
    <mkdir dir="${test.report}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" description="compile the test code" depends="prepare">
    <echo message=" -- testng-compile-examples --" />
    <javac includeantruntime="false" debug="true" fork="true" source="1.6" classpathref="compile.cp" srcdir="${example.dir}/src" destdir="${example.dir}/build/classes" />
</target>

<!-- ==================================================================== -->
<!-- Run Tests                                                            -->
<!-- ==================================================================== -->

<path id="run.cp">
    <path refid="compile.cp" />
    <pathelement location="${example.dir}" />
    <pathelement location="${example.dir}/build/classes" />
</path>

<target name="run" depends="compile" description="Run examples using testng task with just -testclass and no xml">
    <taskdef classpathref="run.cp" name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
    <echo>Starting tests...</echo>
    <testng classpathref="run.cp" outputdir="${test.output}">
        <!-- <classfileset dir="${example.dir}/build/classes/test" /> -->

        <xmlfileset file="${example.dir}/src/testng.xml" />
        <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="Fault Management Functional End to End Test" />
    </testng>
    <echo>Some of these tests should have failed, see the file test.out for the details</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is a question and answer website. So putting question and answer in one post is invalid. So please post your answer using *Answer your own question* as described at http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: @SebastianZartner posted in question and answer format.

Answer (score 6):

The surprise: Eclipse, understood automatically even if there are duplicate jars and was able to run the test scripts. However, ANT could not do that. So, I removed the jar com.google.common, which made me to run the test scripts from command line.

Lesson learnt: Do not have duplicate .jar files.

Comment: Thanks @ASANT I too had similar issue. Sometimes java -verbose:class helps to troubleshoot such issues.

Answer (score -1):

Even i got Similar issue with Maven build :

I have written a utility to generate PDF using Itext library for this i have used one of the available maven repository

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.technbolts</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-contrib</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Which was causing the above issue

Then i have used dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Now its working correctly ... So Lesson learnt choose correct dependency .