# Unable to start the FirefoxDriver using Maven

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

With the help of Maven, I'm trying to launch the firefox browser and passing the google url. But it is not working after the launch of firefox browser.

I have added all the jars in the pom.xml dependency.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The above line is not working and guide me to reach out.

**Code:**

```
public class Test {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Driver is running");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.out.println(driver.toString());
        System.out.println("Driver is running");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
    
    @org.testng.annotations.Test
    public void open(){
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }
    
    @AfterTest
    public void close() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.wait(5000);
    }
}
```

**POM.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.maven.sample</groupId>
 <artifactId>first</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Sample Project</name>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.43.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.10</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Automationsuite">
  <test name="demoTest">
    <classes>
       <class name="first.Test" />
    </classes>
  </test>  
</suite>
```

**Console:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
S@k7computing.com in winreg-app-global
1461736685578   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\MSTEMP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous6839848801827999862webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.42.0","st":1461736684069,"mt":1461736683939}},"app-system-defaults":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.1.14","st":1460445867014}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.2","st":1460445867030}},"winreg-app-global":{"k7srff_enUS@k7computing.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K7 Computing\\K7TSecurity\\K7SR\\K7WebProtection.xpi","e":false,"v":"2.4","st":1451992580000}}}
1461736685579   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1461736685584   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1461736685585   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1461736685600   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
1461736685611   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\MSTEMP\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous6839848801827999862webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1461736685628   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1461736685632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1461736685632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1461736685820   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1461736685820   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1461736685821   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736706152   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
1461736706264   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706264   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1461736706265   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1461736706265   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706265   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706265   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1461736706266   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1461736706267   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1461736706268   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736706270   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1461736706274   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at selenium.Sample.main(Sample.java:14)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
S@k7computing.com in winreg-app-global
1461736685578   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\MSTEMP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous6839848801827999862webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.42.0","st":1461736684069,"mt":1461736683939}},"app-system-defaults":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.1.14","st":1460445867014}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.2","st":1460445867030}},"winreg-app-global":{"k7srff_enUS@k7computing.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K7 Computing\\K7TSecurity\\K7SR\\K7WebProtection.xpi","e":false,"v":"2.4","st":1451992580000}}}
1461736685579   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1461736685584   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1461736685585   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1461736685600   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
1461736685611   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\MSTEMP\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous6839848801827999862webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1461736685628   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1461736685632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1461736685632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1461736685820   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1461736685820   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1461736685821   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736706152   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
1461736706264   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706264   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1461736706265   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1461736706265   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706265   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706265   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1461736706266   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1461736706267   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1461736706268   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736706270   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1461736706274   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

Build info: version: '2.42.0', revision: '5e824302019c86eae9c8c3ca9155e7307b410cf8', time: '2014-05-24 09:48:41'
System info: host: 'VenkateshBabuRM', ip: '10.0.0.7', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at selenium.Sample.main(Sample.java:14)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
S@k7computing.com in winreg-app-global
1461736685578   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\MSTEMP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous6839848801827999862webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.42.0","st":1461736684069,"mt":1461736683939}},"app-system-defaults":{"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.1.14","st":1460445867014}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.2","st":1460445867030}},"winreg-app-global":{"k7srff_enUS@k7computing.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K7 Computing\\K7TSecurity\\K7SR\\K7WebProtection.xpi","e":false,"v":"2.4","st":1451992580000}}}
1461736685579   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1461736685584   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1461736685585   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\loop@mozilla.org.xpi
1461736685600   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
1461736685611   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\MSTEMP\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous6839848801827999862webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1461736685616   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1461736685627   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1461736685628   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1461736685631   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1461736685632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1461736685632   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1461736685820   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1461736685820   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1461736685821   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736685912   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736706152   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method shutdown on loop@mozilla.org version 1.1.14
1461736706264   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706264   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1461736706265   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1461736706265   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706265   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
1461736706265   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1461736706266   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1461736706267   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1461736706268   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1461736706270   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
1461736706274   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: which browser version and selenium version are u using..Latest recommended config is to use 2.53.0 with FF 45.x

Comment: With the latest version as I updated in the pom.xml, I'm getting the below exception.

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;**

Comment: @MrunalGosar I currently installed the 45.0.2 version. Do I need to mention that in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go step by step: 
1. Create a simple maven project and just add selenium-java latest library
2. create a simple Java class with a main method having only one line invoking firefox browser
3.  try running that 
Next Step: 
1. Add latest testng dependency to your maven pom file. 
2. Create a TestNG class and copy paste the same code from main class to the test class method.
3. Right click and say run as Testng (If you have TestNG plugin installed for eclipse)

Comment: How to call the main class through pom.xml without testng.
As of now in dependencies I have added the selenium-java & maven-compiler-plugins.
Console Output:
**BUILD SUCCESS**

Comment: aye..simply do a right click on the class and run it and see if it runs..also try to open some public url..by calling browser instance.get("url")

Comment: In dependencies I removed the maven-compiler-plugins and with selenium-java 2.53.0 I run as a Java application to open the google website and it works good.
When I run the project as **maven test**, the browser itself not opened and no exception in the console. I got a message like **BUILD SUCCESS**

Comment: Ok..so now its clear there is no issue with selenium and ur browser setting. See next step in the solution.

Comment: the reason browser did nit open is because here is no test in that project apparently

Comment: In the dependencies I had selenium-java & testng and in the plugins I have maven-surefire-plugin.
Previously in addition to the two above dependencies **maven-compiler-plugin** also availed in the dependencies.
Now I removed the maven-compiler-plugin from the dependencies and everything goes fine now.
Actually what is the purpose of that dependency do I need to add? or I can avoid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110340/discussion-between-ashok-kumar-and-mrunal-gosar).

Comment: sorry mate..no access to chat feature.. But the issue is not with the maven-compiler-plugin..but probably with either compiler version u've specified or the compatibility of 2.53.0 with FF 45.x as against using 2.48.0 with FF 45.x

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your POM.xml dependencies to the newest versions:

```
Selenium to 2.53.0 
TestNG to 6.9.10
guava to 19.0
```

Edit:
You can also try updating your maven-surefire-plugin to 2.19.1

Comment: I upgraded to newest versions and I got the below exception.
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;**

Comment: I assume it's Google guava error (I never used it before). Try running your test as before, but with old version of guava. They may have dropped support for method mentioned in your error.

Comment: When I use Selenium 2.43.0 I get the console error, When I use Selenium 2.53.0 I get the exception error as I mentioned in the comment. It looks like not a guava error. Any suggestions?

Comment: If I run without maven, it works very well with testng or without testng too. When it comes with maven, not even new firefox instance is getting created.

Comment: Try looking for duplicate .jar files. Very similar guava error was mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088899/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-when-trying-to-run-via-ant If you're using Eclipse, it understands automatically even if there are duplicate jars and is able to run your test scripts.

Comment: In Maven dependencies library, there is no duplication. When ever I edit the pom.xml, the workspace is getting rebuild so, duplication is avoided.

Comment: Any idea about the below exception
**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055; process output follows: 
3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"45.0.2","st":1460445867030}},"winreg-app-global":{"k7srff_enUS@k7computing.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\K7 Computing\\K7TSecurity\\K7SR\\K7WebProtection.xpi","e":false,"v":"2.4","st":1451992580000}}}**

Comment: Sorry, but you will have to try your luck with someone else.

Comment: Ok let me look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the same issue. Below how I solved it.

- Firstly, check that your Test class in under src/test/java after creating a maven project.
- Secondly, you should save your pom.xml file and update your maven project
  If you are working with eclipse:
  Right click on your project - Select Maven and update project
- Afterwards, check that all annotations are imported:
  `import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;`
  `import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;`
  `import org.testng.annotations.Test;`
- Then, you can test your maven project.
  If you are working with eclipse:
  Right click on your project - Select Run as and click on Maven test.
- Therefore, there is no use testing a maven project by running TestNG framework.

Comment: Whether you're working with firefox, you should set the gecko driver System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","Path to the Firefox driver");                                          or the Chrome driver  with google Chrome    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver,"Path to the Chrome Driver");