# Connecting Mozilla fire fox using selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to connect sample websites, using selenium but facing the following error.

```
Feb 22, 2017 1:19:46 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues(Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ListMultimap;
    at com.google.common.net.MediaType.toString(MediaType.java:708)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:597)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:210)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:123)
    at com.mozilla.service.ConncetMozilla.main(ConncetMozilla.java:11)
```

Comment: Read Post. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the following error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Multimaps.transformValues`

For some reason you are missing the jar's containing the `transformValues` method.

Possible causes:

- Missing jar's
- Duplicate and or conflicting jar's: [Selenium webdriver throws exception when trying to run via ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25088899/selenium-webdriver-throws-exception-when-trying-to-run-via-ant)
- Incompatible browser / Selenium versions: upgrade everything to latest version.

Other locations describing this error with possible fix:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/appium-discuss/ktv6JN1dEcw/yl0riYd1XEgJ